# My Postsharp tracer attribute logs some classes/methods but not others

Tags: postsharp

**Background**

I'm using Postsharp version 3.0.42.9 and have created a custom tracer attribute (`OnMethodBoundaryAspect`). I have applied it at the assembly level of my WebForms project like this:

```
[assembly: MyLogging.Tracer(AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: MyLogging.Tracer(AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetMembers = "regex:^get_|^set_", AttributePriority = 2)]
```

The tracer logs entry with method arguments and exit with return value. I'm using NLog to write the log entries to a database table.

I have the following two classes in separate files in the same folder of the same project in my solution and in the same namespace:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public OperationResult PerformOperation(IEnumerable<SomeDto> parameters)
    {
        var classB = new ClassB();
        return classB.AnotherOperation(parameters);
    }        
}

//In a different file
public class ClassB
{
    public OperationResult AnotherOperation(IEnumerable<SomeDto> parameters)
    {
        //Do some stuff
        return operationResult;
    }
}
```

`ClassA` is instantiated and invoked from an `aspx` page.

**Problem**

I get the logs as expected for the methods in `ClassA` such as `PerformOperation` and the `aspx` page, but nothing gets logged for any methods in `ClassB`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am logging to a database table and one of the columns was not large enough to hold the data. When I turned on internal logging for NLog it put me on track to resolve the issue. This was not caused by Postsharp.